# Rails - Assets = false, raise runtimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, runtime-error, thin

I want to be able to change css dynamicly when I develope, but when I try to do this

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

I get this error when starting the server with [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/).

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/less-rails-2.2.2/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:22:in `block in <class:Railtie>': The less-rails plugin requires the asset pipeline to be enabled. (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: so how to you plan to compile less into css>

Comment: @lulalala The issue I'm having is that the development is going very slow for me, I have to rake assets:precompile every time I need to see the changes made in css files, and thoser are not in "less" format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the asset pipeline enabled if you want to use the LESS gem.

Also, you don't have to precompile the assets in development. Perform a `rake assets:clean` to remove all your precompile assets and let the asset pipeline do its work. Also make sure that your development.rb file is the default one.

I'm also using less and bootstrap with Rails and I don't have to do any precompile in development mode.